# How can I connect to a different database with aws sam and sequelize when its locally deployed?

Tags: sequelize.js, aws-sam

I would like to use a local mysql database when I'm testing aws sam locally and use my aurora database when its deployed. I am using sequelize with a config file as an ORM. This config file has different mysql settings for development, testing and production. Ideally I would like to set it to dev on my local machine and to testing when its uploaded. Is there a way I can do this, so it automatically switches to the relevant config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running your app locally with `sam` there's an environment variable set called `AWS_SAM_LOCAL`.

It sounds like you'll want to write a simple function that gets you the right database-connection requirements (endpoint, username, password) depending on if you're running locally or deployed.

You might have something like:
`const runningServerLocally = process.env.AWS_SAM_LOCAL === 'true'`

Yes, that's the string `'true'` which Amazon's team has set that to... but that's the code that works for me! Happy coding!